# how to toggle using onclick attribute of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

So, I have created a clickable div by putting onclick=" " attribute of HTML, it allows me to show my custom modal, now on my custom modal I have created another div with onclick, both divs has the same function on it like onclick="open__instruments()".

to better understand the structure, i have attached a code:

```
 <div class="w-full h-10 flex gap-2 relative" onclick="open__instruments()" id="creates__area">
      <div class="w-full h-full shrink-0 rounded-lg text-green4 hover:text-blue-text bg-white shadow-shadow1 flex justify-center items-center gap-2 hover:bg-green2 select-none">
          <span class="material-symbols-rounded">add</span>
          <div class="w-fit h-fit font-semibold py-2.5 ">Create</div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-[11rem] p-1 bg-white shadow-xl h-fit absolute -right-[11.7rem] rounded-lg hidden" id="instruments">
         <div class="w-full h-10 text-gray-600 rounded-md left_flex pl-3 hover:bg-green2 hover:text-blue-text font-semibold cursor-pointer" onclick="open__instruments()">New Area</div>
         <div class="w-full h-10 text-gray-600 rounded-md left_flex pl-3 hover:bg-green2 hover:text-blue-text font-semibold cursor-pointer mt-1" onclick="open__instruments()">New Parameter</div>
         <div class="w-full h-10 text-gray-600 rounded-md left_flex pl-3 hover:bg-green2 hover:text-blue-text font-semibold cursor-pointer mt-1" onclick="open__instruments()">New Task</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

when I click that it will show the modal I created:

[image]

Now when i click New Area or New Parameter or New Task in my modal, the modal won't close, but when i click the +create div/button it will hide the modal.

below is the javascript function of  onclick="open__instruments()":

```
const open__instruments = ()=>{
    if(document.getElementById('instruments').classList.contains('hidden')){
        document.getElementById('instruments').classList.remove('hidden')
    }else{
        document.getElementById('instruments').classList.add('hidden')
    }
}
```

how am i able to hide the modal by clicking a menu/button/div in my modal?
BTW, i have also created separate function for toggling the modal but it still doesn't work, also, there is no error in the console.

Comment: This is because the click event bubbles up the DOM. You click on "New Area", the instruments div currently does not have the class hidden, so it gets added. But now after that, the click handler on the parent div fires as well - the instruments div does have the class hidden now, so it gets removed again ...

Comment: Oh, that's insightful, thank you for that @CBroe